# Data Replication in Oracle

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a table on master site which only allow insert operation. I want to replicate the rows which are inserted recently so, need something which can track the last record replicated into the local site and perform the replication afterwards.

I have tried Oracle materialized view but still confuse that whether I use the Fast Refresh or Complete Refresh. I need all the newly inserted rows replicated in one transaction.

Are there any better approach to do that? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do this for one table or a whole set of tables. When you say you want to insert the replicated rows in one transaction what exactly do you mean. Do you want to insert at specific intervals. Also, when you say you want to perform replication afterwards does it imply that you don't want near real time data replication. Also, what is the exact intent of this replication (Are you building a DR site?, will users query the access data for reporting purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast refresh would copy incremental changes over the network but requires that a materialized view log be created on the master site on the source table.  That adds some overhead to the inserts happening on the master table but would generally make the refresh more efficient.

A complete refresh would copy every row over the network every time the materialized view is refreshed.  That is likely to be less efficient from a refresh perspective but there will be no overhead to inserts on the source table and the master site does not need to create a materialized view log.

Oracle provides a host of data replication technologies-- materialized views are the oldest and probably the least efficient but are relatively trivial to set up.  Streams is a newer technology that has much lower overhead but is quite a bit more complex to set up.  Golden Gate is the preferred replication technology today but that has extra licensing costs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The materialized view is created from the another view in the master database and that view is created by the combination of multiple tables. We don't want to make the logs for each table involved. 

Complete refresh is less efficient I guess because we need to fetch the record frequently (every second). I did that with the scheduler by writing below query.

`INSERT INTO ARIX_FOO F_FOO (SELECT L_FOO.ID , L_FOO.BAR FROM ARIX_FOO@link L_FOO where L_FOO.ID > (SELECT NVL(MAX(ID),0) FROM ARIX_FOO));`

Is there any other way to do it efficiently?

Comment: @UmairAnsari - That is unlikely to work unless there is a single-threaded process inserting data in the source database.  What happens if the `id` value 2 gets committed just before the `id` value 1?  You might see 2 and never see 1.  It sounds like you may want the extra complexity of either Streams of GoldenGate.